# scipy.stats.pearsonr complaining about operand type -: 'tuple' and 'float'

Tags: python, scipy

[image: Dataframe]

I am trying to calculate the correlation between the two columns of a numpy 2D array. The array looks like:

---

```
a = np.array([[5.1, 3.5, 1.4, 0.2],
        [4.9, 3. , 1.4, 0.2],
        [4.7, 3.2, 1.3, 0.2],
        [4.6, 3.1, 1.5, 0.2]])
```

---

so the correlation between 1st and 3rd column is being calculated as:

---

```
import scipy
x, y = scipy.stats.pearsonr(a[:,0], a[:,2])
```

---

However, it complains:

---

```
unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'tuple' and 'float'
```

---

This means ,for example, something like below is happening:

---

```
print((0.1,0.2) - 0.3)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'tuple' and 'float'
```

---

UPDATE:
The complete code:

---

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy import stats
import numpy as np
a = pd.read_csv("src/iris.csv").drop('species', axis=1).values
def lengths():
    x, y = stats.pearsonr(a[:,0],a[:,2])
    return x, y
print(lengths())
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an issue with your data. Using your code with another Iris dataframe from [vega-datasets](https://github.com/vega/vega-datasets), I have no issues calculating the correlation:

```py
import pandas as pd
from scipy import stats
import numpy as np
import vega_datasets as vd

a = vd.data.iris().drop('species', axis=1).values
def lengths():
    x, y = stats.pearsonr(a[:,0],a[:,2])
    return x, y
print(lengths())
```

returns

```
(0.8717537758865832, 1.0386674194497525e-47)
```

Comment: yes, there was something wrong with loading the data, now got it working